# Error when posting questions or checking posts on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I have recently signed in into Stack Exchange, I am finding it really interesting when the experts give suggestions or answers for my questions within no time.. So I gave a thought of downloading app in mobile for Stack Exchange through Play Store.

1. I downloaded the app and it was successful.
2. Logged in and that's fine.
3. I tried to access my profile and tried posting questions and checking my posts but it throws an ANR (Application Not Responding) dialog like below. So is the applications user specific or depends on the mobile?

   > Do you want to close it?
   >   Wait | Report | OK

Even though my internet connection is good, it still throws the same error? I tried to reinstall but still nothing changed. Should I access this only through computer and not through my mobile? Can I get some other options for the usage of it?

Comment: The mobile app is still in development and may (will) still have a few bugs. Could you say what system you're running on and post a screen shot? In the mean time there is also the mobile version of the website

Comment: What exactly did you do that caused the "Do you want to close" dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and bringing me in my notice that its still under development. If this is the case then there has to be certain messages displayed into it so that the users will not face any issues. Well, its not that I cannot login but I cannot access the sites to check my profile or any details regarding my questions and answers. All of sudden a message pops up as I have specified earlier.

Comment: Seems like something running in the background of the app is making you crash if it's happening randomly. We get reports for all of these automatically and are fixing them with every update.

Comment: Thanks so much @KasraRahjerdi as that wud be useful to us when we access in mobile.Please let me know if you need a QA on that, I wud be there for your help :)

Comment: I believe your options are "Wait, **Report**, **OK**" when it force closes. The appropriate thing to do is hit "Report". Crash reports are automatically forwarded to the developer.

Comment: I know this is an old bug report, but I just want to know if this issue is still reproducible on your side or not. I have never receiving ANR dialog on v1.0.83 (current latest version). Otherwise, this report might be closed as "no repro".